# ¿Como serializar una imagen (bitmap) en bytes[ ] C# UWP?

Tags: c#, imagen, serialización, uwp

Lo que pasa es que tengo una imagen capturada desde una carpeta del PC

```
//Capturar imagen
//https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers

var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file == null)
      return;
```

Despues de capturarla la muestro en una `<Image/>` por medio de Binding al ViewModel desde el XAML

```
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="150" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

y este es el el codigo del View Model, creo la propiedad a la que voy a hacerle Binding:

```
public ImageSource CurrentImage { get { return currentImage; } set { Set(ref currentImage, value); } }
private ImageSource currentImage;
```

y dentro del metodo va asi:

```
//Mostrar en <Image/>
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214553/binding-image-source-to-page
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(await file.OpenReadAsync());
this.CurrentImage = bitmap;
```

**Ahora lo que nesecito es Serializarla en bytes para guardarlo en la base de datos y no he podido**

vi este video y no me sirve, la propiedad Image me genera error, nome aparece, no se si tenga que importar alguna libreria: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUTdln165aw

tambien mire este Blog y no me sirve, no me deja importar `System.Drawing.Image`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array

y no se como podria hacer la serializacion en UWP con C#

Comment: Pero...de que tipo es la imagen que intentas serializar? es un `BitmapImage`?

Comment: Si, eso se puede?

Comment: Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36140365/) a ver si te sirve

Comment: ya halle la solucion asi que lo dejare como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione. el codigo para pasar a Bytes un BitmapImage en UWP es este, se deja lo otro lo tenia y se hace esto:

```
using Windows.Storage.Streams; //libreria que usaremos
byte[] imageByte = null; //parametro que guardara la conversion de la imagen

//Serializar
using (var inputStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
{
    var readStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    var byteArray = new byte[readStream.Length];
    await readStream.ReadAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    imageByte = byteArray;
}
```

ya lo que hago es enviar `imageBytes` al SQL

y para traerlo de nuevo hacemos esto, teniendo en cuenta que ya tenemos el Binding del `<image/>` en XAML (que aunque arriba explico como hacerlo lo repito):

```
//este es el parametro global que hace Binding en el <image/>
public ImageSource CurrentImage { get { return currentImage; } set { Set(ref currentImage, value); } } 
private ImageSource currentImage;

//Deserializar
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
    {
        writer.WriteBytes(imageByte);
        await writer.StoreAsync();
    }
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);

    this.CurrentImage = image;
}
```

Y listo el pollo, la verdad no es facil encontrar documentacion de UWP pero ahi se hace lo que se puede

Comment: Estupendo,me alegro que hayas podido resolverlo. Recuerda si nadie mas responde aceptar tu respuesta en 48 h :)