# ¿Como guardar en SQL un arreglo de Bytes[ ]?

Tags: c#, sql, array, uwp

Es que tengo una imagen serializada en un arreglo de Bytes en C# - UWP, aqui el post: [¿Como serializar una imagen (bitmap) en bytes[ ] C# UWP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/211903/como-serializar-una-imagen-bitmap-en-bytes-c-uwp/212201?noredirect=1#comment395787_212201)

pero ahora tengo que guardarla en un aBase de Datos en SQL y no se que campo utilizar para eso.

gracias

Comment: si es un byte[] el campo en la db seria el varbinary

Comment: gracias ¿alguna idea de por que me califican mal?

Comment: @Wilmilcard te han calificado mal, por que tu pregunta es muy amplia y pareciera basada en opiniones; la comunidad con gusto te ayudará pero trata de mostrar tu avance por mas mínimo que sea

Comment: pues creo que Stack mejoraria si en verdad se hicieran buenos filtros de preguntas o hubiera una seccion de Blogs o post, hace un tiempo hice un trabajo que si estaba dificil de conseguir documentacion y todo mal explicado, queria enseñar a otros de eso que aprendi y tuve que hacer un pregunta a las 24 horas contestarme, por que obviamente nadie podria hallar la solucion, y creo que a almenos 1 pesona podria servirle... tuve que hacerlo dos veces, pues la primera vez me eliminaron el post sin ninguna razon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se el por que me califican mal, pero para todos los arenosos esta es la respuesta:
Lo que hay que hacer es crear en la tabla de la base de datos un campo `varbinary`.
Luego se convierte la imagen que esta en bytes en string64 y asi se guarda en la BD

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageByte);
```

Y ya cuando se tenga que volver a traer se desconvierte de string64 a Bytes[ ]

```
byte[] bytesConvertBack = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

Para entender lo de los campos revisar la pregunta donde hago la serializacion de Imagen a Bytes en UWP. [¿Como serializar una imagen (bitmap) en bytes[ ] C# UWP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/211903/como-serializar-una-imagen-bitmap-en-bytes-c-uwp/212201?noredirect=1#comment395787_212201)

gracias por nada

Comment: por favor manten el respeto, aunque yo no te voté negativo lee mi comentario arriba para que comprendas mejor que pasó, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: si, yo no le estoy acusando de nada, solo que ya van varias ocaciones en las que hago una pregunta y empiezan a calificar negativamente, y ya me rebote

Comment: ademas lo que mas me molesta es que tras de que es muy difícil encontrar documentación de UWP los pocos post que he hecho los han bajado ¿con que ganas le dan a uno de aprende mas del tema?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto, supongamos q quieres cargar una imagen:
(img es tu archivo) tambien aclaro q estas trajandpo con C# MVC EntityFramework

Esta es la forma:

```
var binarioImagen = new BinaryReader(img.InputStream);
Byte[] imagenFoto = binarioImagen.ReadBytes(img.ContentLength);
```

la en tu Class debe declara una propiedad como un arreglo de byte ejemplo asi:

```
public class Fotos
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string nombre { get; set; }
    public byte[] Foto { get; set; }
}
```

puedes usar el dbContext para guardar la base de datos de SQLServer